# Read Key Value from Consul using XML configuration

Tags: xml, spring-boot, spring-cloud, consul, spring-cloud-consul

Currently, I am trying to work on making my spring boot application to be able to dynamically read the data from Consul KV.

At the moment, I have a class:

**ConsulServiceClientImpl**

```
public class ConsulServiceClientImpl implements ConsulServiceClient {

       private String test;

       public String getTestValueFromConsul() {
          return test;
       }
}
```

and I have defined a bean initialization for the above class in the XML configuration file like following:

**consulConfiguration.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<bean id="consulServiceClient" class="com.example.poc.demo.adaptor.impl.ConsulServiceClientImpl">
    <property name="test" value="${test}" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

And this is how my application class looks like:

**DemoApplication.class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource({"classpath*:consulConfiguration.xml"})
public class DemoApplication {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
       }
}
```

Now, after I have tried to run the app, it gave me an error logs:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'test' of bean
class [com.example.poc.demo.adaptor.impl.ConsulServiceClientImpl]: Bean property 'test' is not
writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return
type of the getter?
```

I am wondering if there is any way that we can bind the KV from Consul by using XML configuration like so ?

Comment: Add `getTest()` and `setTest()` is the error implies?

Comment: Hi @spencergibb . I have tried to add the getter and setter and it works just fine as what I expected. Thank you so much for your help!